# How to alter session with paramiko

Tags: python, linux, ssh, scp, paramiko

I want to write a script using python. It should connect via ssh to the server and execute few commands.
The problem is, it's required to change user during connection.
As example, it's possible in WinSCP:
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_scp#shell (Parameter Shell: You can also make use of the option to alter session startup. For example to change the user after login (known as su))

So to connect with propper rights to my ssh server I must write following command into 'Shell' field in WinSCP:

```
sudo su - user
```

I need this very feature in paramiko.
And I can't execute `sudo su - user` after connection is established, cause my password isn't correct. It works only when I use this 'Shell' field.

Nevertheless, when I'm connecting to the server using PuTTY(win) or ssh(linux), I don't need to enter any options, from the start it allows me to have propper rights. Seems strange for me.

I don't know how to develop it using python/paramiko.
Help me pls.

Comment: I found it. We are using Active Directory authentication for ssh. It covered hete in paramiko's API docs - http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/api/ssh_gss.html It's called GSS. Will provide answer in case I solve this issue.